# Black bears and tan-colored bears catching salmon in Alaska

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients

One of popular tourist attractions in Alaska is watching black bears catch salmon swimming upstream to spawn. Not all "black" bears are black, though- some are tan-colored. Suppose that 6 black bears and 3 tan-colored bears are working the rapids of a salmon stream. Over the course of an hour, 6 different bears are sighted. What is the probability that those 6 include at least twice as many black bears as tan-colored bears?

Attempt: I need to use the hypergeometric distribution. That is P(K chosen) = [r_C_k * w_C_(n-k)]/N_C_n.
There are 6 black bears and 3 tan for a total of 9 bears. Thus, N = 9.
Please can someone please help me? I don't understand this problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This **does not happen** when the sample of 6 sighted bears includes $____$ black bears and $____$ tan-colored bears. There are $k=$ $____$ ways to compose such a sample of 6 bears from the 9 in the stream, and $\ell=$ $____$ ways to compose any sample of 6 bears from the 9 in the stream hence the desired probability is $1-(k/\ell)=$ $____$.

Comment: I can's see your fully explanation. For example n = to a white box and big N.

Comment: @user2318: I think the point is that *you* are supposed to fill in the boxes.

Comment: That--or to explain which precise point is preventing you to do so.